# Javascript methods use

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to create a class in JavaScript that would be inherited and than some of its methods would be overridden.

I am using the following structure :

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.myvar = null;
    this.someotherVar = { someFunction: function(a,b){ function1(a,b); })

}

// some functions 
MyClass.prototype.functionA =  function() {..}
MyClass.prototype.functionB =  function() {functionC();}

//some functions that would be overrided
MyClass.prototype.function1=  function() {...}
MyClass.prototype.functionC=  function() {...}
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. Might `functionC` be a problem to use in `functionB` because it is defined afterwards?
2. How can I relate to `function1` inside `someFunction` in the right way?

Comment: Extremely vague title will not be useful to future visitors to the site with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Might `functionC` be a problem to use in `functionB` because it is defined afterwards?

No. You just have to call it properly:

```
 function() { this.functionC(); }
 //           ^^^^^
```

otherwise the function won't be found.

Of course you also have to make sure that `functionB` is only called once `functionC` is defined.

> 2. How can I relate to `function1` inside `someFunction` in the right way?

A tiny problem is that `someFunction` is not a method of the instance but of another object. To still call the correct `function1`, you can store a reference to the instance in a variable:

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this;
    this.myvar = null;
    this.someotherVar = { 
        someFunction: function(a,b){ 
            self.function1(a,b);
        }
    };
}
```